# request header can't get cookie when using res.cookie of Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

i just want to try basic methods to set cookie and show in request head.

front-end is just a basic html form with username and password text input, use POST method to transfer data.

below is code based on express.

server just receive req.body, then set it as cookie with domain: localhost:1338/base

cookieRouter.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(cookieParser());

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('this is a router base page!');
});

router.get('/index1.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index1.html');
});

router.post('/index1.html', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('name', req.body, { domain: 'localhost:1338', path: '/base' });
    res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieRouter = require('./cookieRouter.js');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('this is home page!');
});
app.use('/base', cookieRouter);
app.listen(1338);
```

after run app.js,  request header has set-cookie value obviously. but can't get it into request header, and req.cookies is empty object {}, even after refreshing the web.

[image]

but if i just use simplest demo, it can work, for instance:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('name', 'test');
});
```

one more thing, i feel the trouble with express is that only one `res.send()`, `res.redirect()`... can be sent as by default it will add head automatically, otherwise, it will come up with error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
someone said add `return` can solve this problem, but i failed, so want to how how to add, can anyone give an complete demo?

Comment: For the `Can't set headers after they are sent` issue, it has nothing to do with cookie and should be a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie is missing because the `domain` attribute is incorrect -- `'localhost:1338'` need to be changed to `'localhost'`. Port information should not be included in `domain`.

Yes, according to the Network panel of browser dev tool, there is a `Set-Cookie` response header (as the screenshot displayed). However, if you check `Application - Cookies` panel in Chrome (or corresponding panel in other browsers), you will find that: the cookie specified by `Set-Cookie` header is not there. Browser does not store it and won't send it in the following HTTP requests.

Also, please note that as the cookie's path is `/base`, only the HTTP requests whose URL starts with `/base` can send the cookie.

Comment: wow, it works as you said, when i set in this way: `res.cookie('name', req.body, { domain: 'localhost', path: '/base' });` this bother me one day and it is just a low-level problem. thanks very much.